# Child theme style.css isn't overwriting parent style.css

Tags: child-theme, css

I am using the Optimizer theme and created a child theme to make 2 changes in the style.css. The .single_wrap adjustment works fine, but the page_head is being ignored. When I use Inspect Element on Google Chrome I can tell the parent style.css overides the child style.css for this part. Page_head is the title banner on my pages. Anyone know what's up?

**style.css**

```
/*
 Theme Name:   optimizer_child
 Template:     optimizer
*/

/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.single_wrap {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
}

.page_head {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );
function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

Website: http://www.gelnagels-gina.be

Comment: If you really want to do it properly, then I recommend this article by Justin Tadlock: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2014/11/03/loading-parent-styles-for-child-themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style is not from parent CSS it is from `themes/optimizer/style_core.css`
Then you can enqueue your child CSS on highest priority.

enqueue the parent style then child style on high priority

```
function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 100 );
```

Comment: Damn, I just noticed that too :P What do you mean by enqueuing for highest priority? SHouldn't I just create a style_core.css in my child theme?

Comment: You are using hook to enqueue your child css or it is hardcoded in you header.

If you are using add_action hook then increase the priority to something 100 or more OR if you just placed it to header then place it just below the `wp_head`

Comment: I am using the `add action`, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by setting the priority. In the code sample I added above, that's all I've got in my `functions.php`.

Comment: like this 
`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style', 100 );`

It will change the position of your style in head I mean below to other css if you require more and increase the number.

Comment: Do it for your child css not for the parent.

Comment: I did it, still doesn't override.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22990/discussion-between-customx-and-sumit).